Permission issues with SMB/NFS
I have NAS drive in my LAN. The drives are formatted in the ext4 file system. When I try to open a ODT document located on it from my PC, running Ubuntu 24.04, I have getting prompt saying that The file has been locked by another user and can be open in R/O mode or as a copy. When I try to do the same from my laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04.4, it is opening in edit mode without any problem.
I am the owner of the files on my NAS, I have configured SMB workgroup in samba daemon on both computers, there in no ~lock files in the directory. How can I fix that with my PC?
A similar issue appears when I had tried to mount this drive through NFS protocol - I have had to enter password every time, when I tried to open mounted directory on PC and it stopped to appear among drives, while before the update to Ubuntu 24.04 it has been appearing. That's why I even try to do it by SMB.

Your question fails to say what is the format of the drives on the NAS. Are they NTFS or what? Please edit the question when answering not use the comment. Do other then ODT docs open OK?

I didn't know that a file system of NAS somehow matters for a client side. None docs are open OK, even DOC(X).

Mount the share using the nobrl option.

I am mounting through the Files app, how to set an option this way?...
